# Make IWebBrowser2 Control safe for scripting

Tags: winapi, iwebbrowser2

I'm using IWebBrowser2 control in my application to display external web pages.
The problem is that the object is not safe for scripting and calls to get_Document fails (with S_FALSE as return value).

I've implemented a new class, IScriptableWebBrowser2 that inherits both from IWebBrowser2 & IObjectSafety, and tried to use it instead of IWebBrowser2 but that didn't do the trick.

How do I make my IWebBrowser2 control safe for scripting ?

```
class IScriptableWebBrowser2 : 
   public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
   public IWebBrowser2,
   public IObjectSafety
{
BEGIN_COM_MAP(IScriptableWebBrowser2)
   COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectSafety)
END_COM_MAP()

    // IObjectSafety implementation
    STDMETHODIMP GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(REFIID riid, 
                                           DWORD *pdwSupportedOptions, 
                                           DWORD *pdwEnabledOptions )
    {
        *pdwSupportedOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | 
                               INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
        *pdwEnabledOptions = *pdwSupportedOptions;
        return S_OK;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(REFIID riid, DWORD dwOptionSetMask, DWORD     dwEnabledOptions)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally had some time to come back to this one..

It turns out that get_Document fails if you call it BEFORE the page completely loaded but the return value (S_FALSE) indicates a completely different error ("not safe for scripting")

btw, Loading local pages will give you the desirable behavior.

Therefore, calling get_Document after the page was loaded (DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2, DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE) will do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you created the browser in a thread and passed it on to another thread.
If that's the case, here's what you should do:

Before passing the `IWebBrowser2` instance to another thread, in the creating thread, call `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`, that will marshal (convert) it to a thread-safe `IStream` object, and only then pass it to the tagert thread.
Later, in the target thread, you should call `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` with the previously marshaled `IStream` instance, which will unmarshal it back to your original object in the target thread (and release the `IStream` object along the way).

[CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I'm accessing the IWebBrowser2 from the same thread.